# How can one make only one side of a physics body active in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have a hero, ground and a table. I want to make a table-top active for collision and contact with hero. But hero should be able not to jump on the top and just run "through" and jump on it, if player wants it, wherever he wants. For better example of what i'm trying to achieve - think about Mario. When you are running on ground, some sky platforms appearing. You could jump on it in the middle of a platform and stay there. So I need physics body to not stop hero when he is contacting it from the bottom, but hold him if he is on top of it. 
 By now i'm using body with texture for table:

```
    self.table.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture:table.texture, size:self.table.size)
self.table.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
self.table.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Table.rawValue
self.table.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Hero.rawValue
self.table.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Hero.rawValue
```

It obviously, is not working. How can I implement such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried changing the platforms collision bitmask but wasn't working fine. I found a different solution.

Inside the update() function you can check the following

```
if player.physicsBody?.velocity.dy <= 0 {
    player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Platform
} else {
    player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None
}
```

In this way, every time the player is going up, it can pass through rocks, and every time it is falling, it can stand.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how your platforms looks like (edge based or volume based bodies) but you can consider some of these:

**1. Checking positions**

- Check if the hero's position.y is beneath/above the platform and  ignore/handle the collision.

**2. Checking velocity**

- Or to check if player node if falling, which is indicated by a negative velocity.dy value.

I can't say if any of these can fully help you with your game or is it possible with your setup, but you can get some basic idea on where to start.

Enabling/disabling collisions can be done by changing player's and platform's collision bitmasks. If possible try to avoid tracking states like *isInTheAir*, *isOnPlatform*, *isFaling*, *isJumping* and similar because it can become messy as number of states grows. For example, instead of adding custom boolean variable called "isFalling" and constantly maintaining its state, you can check if velocity.dy is negative to see if player is falling.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question is actually not too difficult but the implementation into a full fledged game will be much more difficult for you. This is not something for a novice programmer to start out with.

First the same code project (tap/click on screen to jump up):

```
#import "GameScene.h"

typedef NS_OPTIONS(uint32_t, Level1PhysicsCategory) {
    CategoryPlayer  = 1 << 0,
    CategoryFloor0  = 1 << 1,
    CategoryFloor1  = 1 << 2,
};

@implementation GameScene {
    int playerFloorLevel;
    SKSpriteNode *node0;
    SKSpriteNode *node1;
    SKSpriteNode *node2;
}

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor whiteColor];

    node0 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor grayColor] size:CGSizeMake(400, 10)];
    node0.position = CGPointMake(300, 200);
    node0.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:node0.size];
    node0.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    node0.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CategoryFloor0;
    node0.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = CategoryPlayer;
    [self addChild:node0];

    node1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor grayColor] size:CGSizeMake(400, 10)];
    node1.position = CGPointMake(300, 300);
    node1.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:node1.size];
    node1.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    node1.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CategoryFloor1;
    node1.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = CategoryPlayer;
    [self addChild:node1];

    node2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(50, 50)];
    node2.position = CGPointMake(300, 250);
    node2.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:node2.size];
    node2.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CategoryPlayer;
    node2.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = CategoryFloor0;
    [self addChild:node2];

    playerFloorLevel = 0;
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    if(((node2.position.y-25) > (node1.position.y+10)) && (playerFloorLevel == 0)) {
        node2.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = CategoryFloor0 | CategoryFloor1;
        playerFloorLevel = 1;
    }
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
     for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
         CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];
        //SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:touchLocation];

        // change 75 value to 50 to see player jump half way up through floor 1
        [node2.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0, 75)];
    }
}
```

The gist of the code is the player node (node2) has to keep checking its y position (update method) in relation to the other floors. In the example, the player jumps up through floor1. Once the player is higher than floor1, the player node's physics body modifies its collision bit mask to include floor1.

Sounds easy enough. However, in a real game you will have a large number of floors and all floors might not be evenly spaced y distances. You have to keep all that in mind when coding.

Comment: Well, you were right! It's a little bit too difficult for me now. I guess I'll start to search alternative ways to do something like that. But thank you anyway, that a good example of how to do this!

Answer (score 1):

Using swift you can create a sprite node subclass like this:

```
class TableNode: SKSpriteNode {

    var isBodyActivated: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            physicsBody = isBodyActivated ? activatedBody : nil
        }
    }

    private var activatedBody: SKPhysicsBody?

    init(texture: SKTexture) {

        super.init(texture: texture, color: SKColor.clearColor(), size: texture.size())

        // physics body setup. Assuming anchorPoint = (0.5, 0.5)
        let bodyInitialPoint = CGPoint(x: -size.width/2, y: +size.height/2)
        let bodyEndPoint = CGPoint(x: +size.width/2, y: +size.height/2)

        activatedBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeFromPoint: bodyInitialPoint, toPoint: bodyEndPoint)
        activatedBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Table.rawValue
        activatedBody!.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Hero.rawValue

        physicsBody = isBodyActivated ? activatedBody : nil

        name = "tableNode"
    }
}
```

Then, update all tableNodes in the gameScene:

```
override func didSimulatePhysics() {
    self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("tableNode") {
        node, stop in 

        if let tableNode = node as? TableNode {
            // Assuming anchorPoint = (0.5, 0.5) for table and hero
            let tableY = tableNode.position.y + tableNode.size.height/2
            let heroY = hero.position.y - hero.size.height/2
            tableNode.isBodyActivated = heroY > tableY
        }
    }
}
```